# 3 select that send id to other select in laravel 8

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, html-select, laravel-8

The title is a little complicated. I want to transfer a product to a company. I can transfer the same product to another company later. But I didn't know how to do it. I have 3 select's.

1.select imei

2.select companies

3.select the cars of that company

When I select the imei address from the first select, if that device has been transferred to a company, the other selects should be marked automatically. So the second select 'selected' will come automatically. There will be other companies under it. 3. Selectin select will also be marked and other vehicles of the company will be added under it.

If the device is not transferred, all companies will be added to 2. Select first step by step. After selecting the company, the cars of that company will be added to the 3rd select.

It's a bit complicated, I'm sorry.

HTML:

```xml
<div class="modal fade" id="addPostModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addPostModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    {!!BootForm::open([ 'method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'yonetim.devices.TransferDevice', 'files'=> 'true', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data' ])->multipart('multipart/form-data') !!}
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="addPostModalLabel"> Devices </h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"> × </span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Imei</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="device_id" id="device_id">
                                <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">Imei</option>
                                @foreach ($devices as $key => $value)
                                    <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{ $value->imei }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Companies</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="comp_id" id="comp_id">
                                <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">Companies</option>
                                @foreach ($companies as $key => $value)
                                    <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{ $value->comp_name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Car</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="car_id" id="car_id">
                                <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">Car</option>
                                @foreach ($cars as $key => $value)
                                    <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{ $value->plate }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                {!! BootForm::submit('Save')->class('btn btn-success') !!}
                {!!BootForm::close()!!}
            </div>

            <div class="result"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
                
</div>
```

JS:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#device_id').on('change', function(e){
        //console.log(e);
        var device_id = e.target.value;
        //alert(panel);
        $.get('devices/transfer?device_id=' + device_id,function(data) {
            $('#comp_id').empty();
            $('#comp_id').append('<option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">Lütfen Şirket Seçin</option>');

            $.each(data, function(index, villagesObj) {
                $('#comp_id').append('<option value="'+ villagesObj.id +'">'+ villagesObj[Object.keys(villagesObj)[1]] +'</option>');
            })
        });
    });
});
```

Controller:

```php
public function transfer(Request $request)
{
    $device_id = $request->device_id;
    $comp_id = DeviceTra::where('device_id', '=', $device_id)->first();
    $comp_name = '';
    if ($comp_id) {
        $car_id = Cars::where('id', $comp_id->car_id)->first();
        $comp_name = Companies::where('id',$car_id->comp_id)->get();
    }
    return response()->json($comp_name);
}
```

My questions:
After selecting the 1st selection, the 2nd select is marked. But other companies don't insert.
3. How can I fill in the selection?